# How can I save my object in an other table?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have this code :

```
entryA = myTable1.objects.all().first()
entryB = copy.deepcopy(entryA)
```

But the problem is I would want to save `entryB` but if I do `entryB.save()` I will have a new entry in `myTable1` whereas I want to have a new entry in `myTable2` which contains the same fields.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you

Here is my model :

```
class myTable1(models.Model):
    number = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=None)

class myTable2(models.Model):
    number = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=None)
```

Comment: show your models

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to copy the properties of one object to another object and then use the `create` method to create a new instance.

```
class myTable1(models.Model):
    number = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=None)

class myTable2(models.Model):
    number = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=None)

entryA = myTable1.objects.all().first()
entryB = myTable2.objects.create(number=entryA.number, date=entryA.date)
```

Or if you want `myTable2` to have unique data, you can do:

```
 entryA = myTable1.objects.all().first()
 entryB, created = myTable2.objects.get_or_create(number=entryA.number, date=entryA.date)
```